# Extendable Java Database

Tags: java, database, open-source

I'm looking for an open source, Java-based database that ...

- can be easily extended, e.g. by implementing various forms of trees (R-tree, etc.), various indexing techniques (BitMatrix, etc.), new operations and fields
- does a good (fast) job at reading data, e.g. for reading time series
- is well documented

I looked at (in other threads suggested) Apache Derby and BerkleyDB already; at the moment I'm in favor of BerkleyDB since it seems to be faster than Derby. Do you have any further preferences or any arguments for or against a database.

Comment: Check out HSQLDB (aka HyperSQL)

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to extend it but [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) seems to be one of the most flexible and vibrant projects at this time.

It uses interfaces in many places which makes it simple to drop in your own implementation, for example for [custom tables](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#pluggable_tables).

Comment: Yes, seems to have quite a nice and well-documented code!